# Sort list based on character in middle of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in the following format:

```
list_names = ['Name: Mark - Age: 42 - Country: NL',
          'Name: Katherine - Age: 23 - Country: NL',
          'Name: Tom - Age: 31 - Country: NL']
```

As you can see, all the information is set in one string. What I need is to order this list based on the age, which is located somewhere in the middle of the string.

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the exact format of the input...? First you need to find some way to get the age from each string

Comment: Do you know that there is a `sorted` function with a `key` parameter?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes but I'm not sure how to use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to sorting the list by the names stored in the strings is, to extract the age from the string. Once, you have defined a function which does that, you can use the `key` argument of the `.sort` method. Using regular expressions, extracting the age is simple. A solution could look as follows.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'age:\s*(\d+)', re.IGNORECASE)

def extract_age(s):
    return int(pattern.search(s).group(1))

list_names = ['Name: Mark - Age: 42 - Country: NL',
              'Name: Katherine - Age: 23 - Country: NL',
              'Name: Tom - Age: 31 - Country: NL']

list_names.sort(key=extract_age)
print(list_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to capture the age and use it as the sort key.

```
import re

list_names = ['Name: Mark - Age: 42 - Country: NL',
          'Name: Katherine - Age: 23 - Country: NL',
          'Name: Tom - Age: 31 - Country: NL']

def get_age(value):
    match = re.search("Age: (\d+)", value)
    return int(match.group(1))

list_names_sorted = sorted(list_names, key=get_age)
print(list_names_sorted)
```

Output (pretty printed):

```
[
    'Name: Katherine - Age: 23 - Country: NL',
    'Name: Tom - Age: 31 - Country: NL',
    'Name: Mark - Age: 42 - Country: NL'
]
```

Comment: @GaneshGebhard See updated answer. I added the `int()` conversion.